# How to change dead zone / palm detection in xSwipe Gnome Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, thinkpad

So I am using Xswipe to get multi finger gestures working properly in Unbuntu. I am new to linux but have followed many tutorials to get it set up just the way I like. The last nagging issue I have is with xSwipe. When I use the touch pad on my Thinkpad x230 I have to start any movement at all in the middle of the touchpad. If I start anywhere near the sides, top, or bottom it won't register. My guess is this is palm rejection kicking in even though I am not typing at the time. How cna I alter the size of this zone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That was a very helpful document, however Xswipe must be overriding the palm settings as nothing I changed seemed to make a difference :(

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry this is not a proper answer. I dont have enought reputation to create comments. You might want to look at this documentation from the Arch linux community, there you can find some information about how to configure palm detection:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Best,
Luis

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.